# Reloading syntax on vimrc change

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting

My vimrc has a function that extends the default-provided syntax for C:

```
function! Bx_c_syntax() "{{{
    "A faked version of the real thing
    let b:match_words=
                \ '\<BEGIN\>:\<END\?\>,' .
                \ ''
    syn keyword cStructure RECORD
endfunction #}}}
```

It also has this auto-group:

```
augroup Cc
    au!
    au FileType c call Bx_c_syntax()
    "...
augroup END
```

This gives me custom highlights/word-pairs as expected, however, when I resource my `.vimrc` (`:source ~/.vimrc`) I lose the new highlights/word-pairs until I reopen my C files.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

> What am I doing wrong?

Never ever touch `FileType` event. It's for `ftdetect` / `ftplugin` / `indent` / `syntax`, but not for you!

You must put your stuff into `~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim` instead, or whatever your `&runtimepath` is.

But what exactly goes wrong? Well, your vimrc should have `syntax on` or `syntax enable` line somewhere. And the first thing the command `syntax on` does is... it turns the syntax off, so no leftovers are hanging anywhere. After that all the good stuff is restored, but not yours, as it's still awaiting for FileType event to come... in vain.