# Conceal markdown links and extensions

Tags: syntax-highlighting, conceal

I wish to fully conceal markdown links, even if they have extensions. For example:

`[Anchor text](http://whatever...)`

`[Anchor text](http://whatever...){:rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"}`

Should become:

`Anchor text`

I can conceal the `()` and its content, and the `{}` and its content. However, I can't hide the characters `[]`.

Moreover, concealing all this long text sometimes generates a ghost line below, because it's really there, concealed! Is there a way to hide the gost newline?

This is my code:

```
    autocmd Filetype markdown,liquid,text
                \ syn region markdownLink matchgroup=markdownLinkDelimiter
                \ start="(" end=")" keepend contained conceal contains=markdownUrl
    autocmd Filetype markdown,liquid,text
                \ syn match markdownExt /{[.:#][^}]*}/ conceal contains=ALL
```

My result is:

`[Anchor text]`

Comment: The [vim-markdown](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown) plugin allows to conceal links.

Comment: Yes, I checked its code to do the mine and it was helpful. However, it does not conceal the extensions and it uses scopes in coherence with its own syntax definitions, while I prefer to use the standard syntax of vim. I also checked mkdx plugin, which was helpful for me as well.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, thanks! :)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, I installed the vim-markdown plugin by plasticboy for a while, to test if it removes the ghost line, and it doesn't. I think this is an opportunity to improve a tool if we put our efforts on it. I feel I can't do that by myself. I hope it's possible to achieve this.

Comment: @Gerard what do you mean with the ghost line? If this is about wrapping earlier than expected, than it is not possible to change. Vim will always wrap on the line content and not about the visual representation of the line.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/260

Comment: Yes, @ChristianBrabandt, it's this wrap issue when conceallevel > 0. As I can see, this won't be fix. Thanks for that link, @Rich. Then, the only thing I would like to fix is to remove the `[]` when concealing.

Comment: @Gerard Could you just clarify what you mean by "it uses scopes in coherence with its own syntax definitions". I don't want to propose a solution that you're dissatisfied with,

Comment: @Rich, yeah, I meant plasticboy's plugin is a full featured package that defines a lot of new syntax scopes to reuse them in the next definitions. I would like to have something more simple, using the syntax default for vim or perhaps creating one new syntax if it's needed, like I did with `markdownExt`. Still, I'm not sure if I did it well... All improvements are welcome!

Comment: @Rich, as I can see, it's called `markdownLinkTextDelimiter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to overwrite the existing `markdownLinkText` syntax item with one that conceals the `[` and `]` delimiters:

This item is currently defined with the following line from `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/markdown.vim` (line continuations added by me for Stack Exchange formatting purposes):

```
syn region markdownLinkText matchgroup=markdownLinkTextDelimiter
    \ start="!\=\[\%(\_[^]]*]\%( \=[[(]\)\)\@=" end="\]\%( \=[[(]\)\@="
    \ nextgroup=markdownLink,markdownId skipwhite
    \ contains=@markdownInline,markdownLineStart
```

This highlights the ends of the region (i.e. the `[` and `]` delimiters) with the `markdownLinkTextDelimiter` group via [`matchgroup`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-matchgroup). To instead make it conceal them, tack [`concealends`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-concealends) onto the end:

```
syn region markdownLinkText matchgroup=markdownLinkTextDelimiter
    \ start="!\=\[\%(\_[^]]*]\%( \=[[(]\)\)\@=" end="\]\%( \=[[(]\)\@="
    \ nextgroup=markdownLink,markdownId skipwhite
    \ contains=@markdownInline,markdownLineStart
    \ concealends
```

The downside of this approach is that if the existing syntax definition is altered to handle more cases, then you may need to update your tweaked version, too. I'm guessing the markdown link syntax is reasonably stable at this point, so hopefully this will work well for you.

This will take precedence over the existing item so long as it is defined later, so putting it `.vim/after/syntax/markdown.vim` is the best place for it. (Putting it in a `FileType` autocommand should work too, [but there are caveats](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/26814/343).)

Comment: Exactly, it works perfect! With reason I was not able to implement it, because it's difficult. I normally add this things in my .vimrc file. Should I add this into the folder `~/.vim/after/syntax/markdown.vim`?

Comment: @Gerard Yes, `~/.vim/after/syntax/markdown.vim` seems to be the appropriate place for this override.

Comment: Thanks, @filbranden. I moved the syntax definitions in that file, however, my `markdownExt` is not working. It worked before, probably by mistake? If I have to fix something, I don't know what it is. At the moment I'm reading `:syn-match`, still I'm not sure if it's the `syn-region`...

Comment: @Gerard Do you mean `markdownLinkText`?

Comment: @filbranden, `markdownExt`, the syntax definition I made to conceal extended markdown, for example `{: ... }`, with this regex that matches all the cases: `/{[.:#][^}]*}/ `. It's in the code of my first post. Edit: The regex works, but the concealing is not working.

Comment: @Gerard But I thought that one didn't work... Why are you not using Rich's suggestion of redefining `markdownLinkText` to include `concealends` instead? Your first comment implies that that worked for you...

Comment: @filbranden. Yes, that worked for me before. It stopped working when I moved it to the file `~/.vim/after/syntax/markdown.vim `. Rich's solution helped to conceal the `[ ... ]` (square brackets). Probably I should redefine the first. However, some links have extension, some links don't have. I'm not sure if it's possible with only one `syn`.

Comment: @Gerard Sorry, I'm not sure I can follow what's going on with your configs... Perhaps you should post a new question about it, with all the details? Reference this question if you do post a new one...

Comment: @filbranden. Simply, after moving all my syntaxes to the `markdown.vim` file instead of using `Filetype` on my `vimrc`, this line is not concealing the extended markdown: `syn match markdownExt /{[.:#][^}]*}/ conceal contains=ALL`.

Comment: @Gerard It looks like it's an ordering issue... Maybe your syntax needs to be first for it to work? It can get quite complex, especially when you're overriding entries from a separate syntax file...

Comment: @filbranden, it's very strange... I'm trying all order positions and it's still not working. Using just this line on my `.vimrc` then it works...

Comment: @filbranden, fixed! I had defined the same without concealing in my own colorscheme (vim-atomic), so it was not concealing...

Comment: Do you have a similar code for Latex `\href{http://...}{text}` links?

Comment: @Grwlf I think you should probably ask that as a separate question.